# Visual Studio C# MS SQL Server: как достать отдельные данные из запроса select?

Tags: c#, sql-server

`Visual Studio С# + MS SQL Server 2008`. Каким образом можно получить отдельные поля запроса. К примеру:

1. создал переменную
2. сделал запрос (к примеру `select * from ****` и т.д.)
3. при занесении в таблицу все нормально, а вот если мне нужно сделать чтобы данные попадали в поля формы (например `Edit1 = "цена"`)

Притом подключение через НЕ визуальные средства, а через обычные SQL-запросы принципиально. В общем нужно как в PHP.

Comment: Что значит "как в PHP"? В PHP то для общения с базой ORM-ы сейчас всюду принято использовать, а не "обычные SQL-запросы".

Answer (score 3):

Я делал в свое время как то так:

```
sqlReader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();
if (sqlReader.HasRows)
{
    while (sqlReader.Read())
    {
        _equipment.Id = (int)sqlReader.GetValue(0);
        _equipment.Type = (int)sqlReader.GetValue(1);
        _equipment.Name = (string)sqlReader.GetValue(2);
        _equipment.Model = (string)sqlReader.GetValue(3);
        _equipment.ReleaseDate =  sqlReader.IsDBNull(4) == true ? null : (DateTime?)sqlReader.GetValue(4);
        _equipment.Unit = sqlReader.IsDBNull(5) == true ? null : (int?)sqlReader.GetValue(5);
        _equipment.Serial = (string)sqlReader.GetValue(6);
        _equipment.Inventory = (string)sqlReader.GetValue(7);
        _equipment.Operational = (string)sqlReader.GetValue(8);
        _equipment.State = sqlReader.IsDBNull(9) == true ? null : (int?)sqlReader.GetValue(9);
        _equipment.ServiceUnit = (string)sqlReader.GetValue(10);
        _equipment.AttachedStaff = (string)sqlReader.GetValue(11);
    }
    sqlReader.Close();
}
```

А вообще ORM может сильно облегчить жизнь.

Comment: `if` в принципе избыточен, поскольку если запрос вернул пустое множество, то первый вызов `Read()` сразу вернет `false`.

Answer (score 1):

```
using (var sqlReader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (sqlReader.Read())
    {
        _equipment.Id = (int)sqlReader[0];
        _equipment.Type = (int)sqlReader[1];
        _equipment.Name = (string)sqlReader[2];
        // ...
        _equipment.AttachedStaff = (string)sqlReader[11];
    }
}
```